# "Unresolved dependency" / "import cannot be resolved" in VS Code Java language support when working with Artifactory dependecies

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code, artifactory

We have a bunch of private Java dependencies published to Artifactory. We are using Gradle to build our project.

The issue is that VSCode Language Support for Java does not recognize the dependencies / imports in `build.gradle` or in our Java source code.

*Note: All the snippets below were copy-pasted exactly from the source code / VS Code messages, with the exception of the company domain being replaced with mycompany.com and the Artifactory credentials redacted.*

The errors I'm seeing in the Java source code are:

```
The import com.mycompany.observability cannot be resolved
```

```
MycompanyLogger cannot be resolved
```

Here is the Java file with the errors:

```
package com.mycompany.sample;

import com.mycompany.observability.logging.MycompanyLogger;

public class SampleApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MycompanyLogger.setServiceName("SERVICE_NAME");
  }
}
```

And the errors in `build.gradle`:

```
Unresolved dependency: com.mycompany:core-observability-spring:0.0.37
```

Here is the `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'application'
    id 'checkstyle'
    id 'pmd'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'com.jfrog.artifactory' version "4.17.2"
    id "org.sonarqube" version "3.0"
}

group = 'com.mycompany'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

jar.archiveBaseName = "sample-service"
mainClassName = 'com.mycompany.sample.SampleApplication'

apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: "java"

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/"
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-release'
            username = project.findProperty('artifactory_user')
            password = project.findProperty('artifactory_key')
            maven = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
    implementation('org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:3.1.0') // Conditional expressions in logback
    implementation('org.codehaus.janino:janino:3.1.0') // Conditional expressions in logback
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
    implementation('net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:6.3')
    implementation('com.datadoghq:dd-java-agent:0.51.0')

    implementation('com.mycompany:core-observability-spring:0.0.37')
}

checkstyle {
    toolVersion "8.29"
    configFile = file("${rootDir}/config/checkstyle/google_checks.xml")
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

pmd {
    ignoreFailures = false
    ruleSetFiles = files("config/pmd/mycompany_custom_ruleset.xml")
    ruleSets = []
    sourceSets = []
}
```

and here are the relevant files in my `~/.gradle/` directory:

```
➜  .gradle cat gradle.properties
artifactory_user=<redacted>
artifactory_key=<redacted>
```

```
➜  .gradle cat init.gradle.kts  
settingsEvaluated {
    pluginManagement {
        val artifactory_user: String? by settings
        val artifactory_password: String? by settings
        val artifactory_key: String? by settings

        repositories {
            maven(url = "https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/gradle-release") {
                credentials {
                    username = artifactory_user
                    password = artifactory_password ?: artifactory_key
                }
            }
            gradlePluginPortal()
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, here are my `.vscode` config files for this project:

```
➜  .vscode git:(vscode-settings) cat settings.json 
{
    "[java]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
    "files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "terminal.integrated.scrollback": 10000,
    "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic",
    "java.import.gradle.enabled": true,
    "java.import.gradle.wrapper.enabled": true,
    "java.import.maven.enabled": false,
}
```

```
➜  .vscode git:(vscode-settings) cat extensions.json 
{
    "recommendations": [
        "gabrielbb.vscode-lombok",
        "pivotal.vscode-spring-boot",
        "richardwillis.vscode-gradle-extension-pack",
        "vscjava.vscode-java-pack"
    ]
}
```

Everything works fine when compiling the app using `./gradlew build`:

```
➜  sample-service git:(master) ✗ ./gradlew build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
11 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

Any ideas on what should be my next steps in debugging this?

Comment: Does it _literally_ say `Unresolved dependency: com.redacted:some-library:0.1.2` or did you change that name? Because if the package name itself already "tells people too much" about your code, then as part of [asking a good question](/help/how-to-ask), create a [mcve] that *can* be shown off without redacting. We don't care about your code, we just care about helping you fix a problem. If you can't show your real code, reduce your code to a toy implementation that you verified still shows off the problem, and then just show that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, very fair point. As you can imagine, creating a minimal reproducible example would take days in this. Would you say it's clear after my last edit?

Comment: Actually I think there is more I can do / share here. On it.

Comment: Ok, done - I think this should be pretty decent. Thank you for the feedback @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: You can add the other dependency which is also under com.mycompany:core-observability-spring:0.0.37's repository to check if you connect to it successfully. If successful connection, Check if there's something wrong with dependency's name and version number. More even, Is it possible that the dependency itself has something wrong?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue and what helped me was running

`Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace` from `Command Palette`.

[image]

It seems like Java Language Server is holding to old version.